# Spring Resource Server + Spring Security O2Auth (Google). Failed to authenticate since the JWT was invalid

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth

I'm trying to implement "Login with google" authorization for my pet project. I decided to practice on a small project first so I created a simple REST app with just one controller. I managed to get through all steps of creating a project in google console, created all necessary keys there and successfully got google token into postman headers. It looks like this `ya29.A0AVA9y1v0OZNHTtELFgP-OGQdT_GY_V9mJ3FKXB2ZcOYjS7_AWx2nX1IzP8Sfnr9uxosNZNyNZK2h_q4zF1Qvhhu2bptv-tL-kSn3qVjHwfDdjqIydn3bKBkqVhIHKhmCE3PLrXuSuDJ2sML-66uFFwR28IpyaCgYKATASATASFQE65dr8xXC0Q6jWHExbZ0yL0utlKw0163`

So I started to implement the spring boot app and ran into some problems. I configured spring security following along tutorials on the web, placed all client ids and all that stuff into application.properties and ran my application. Surprise, nothing works. I started digging and found out that JwtAuthenticationProvider complains that he "`Failed to authenticate since the JWT was invalid`". After some googling I found out that google so called "access_token" is not an actual JWT token, but i don't know what to do with this information. I must be missing something crucial but I don't know what.

my SpringSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
class SpringSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt()
            .and()
            .and()
            .cors().and().csrf().disable()
        return http.build()
    }

}
```

My propperties:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-id=<MY_CLIENT_ACTUAL_VALUE>
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-secret=<MY_SECRET_ACTUAL_VALUE>
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.scope=openid,profile,email
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=https://accounts.google.com
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri=https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs
```

My controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
class TestController {

    @GetMapping(path = ["/alive"])
    private fun alive() = "OK"

}
```

after I try to connect with postman with token header I get this:

```
************************************************************

Request received for GET '/api/alive':

org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@51219c91

servletPath:/api/alive
pathInfo:null
headers: 
authorization: Bearer ya29.A0AVA9y1v0OZNHTtELFgP-OGQdT_GY_V9mJ3FKXB2ZcOYjS7_AWx2nX1IzP8Sfnr9uxosNZNyNZK2h_q4zF1Qvhhu2bptv-tL-kSn3qVjHwfDdjqIydn3bKBkqVhIHKhmCE3PLrXuSuDJ2sML-66uFFwR28IpyaCgYKATASATASFQE65dr8xXC0Q6jWHExbZ0yL0utlKw0163
user-agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.2
accept: */*
postman-token: b6dd2ef8-a4e5-46bf-8d62-141831146efb
host: localhost:8080
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
connection: keep-alive
cookie: JSESSIONID=715201B0645DD1329566CD5AB8509BE6


Security filter chain: [
  DisableEncodeUrlFilter
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  CorsFilter
  LogoutFilter
  BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]


************************************************************


2022-08-19 17:07:29,005 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy: Securing GET /api/alive
2022-08-19 17:07:29,009 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter: Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2022-08-19 17:07:29,031 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider: Failed to authenticate since the JWT was invalid
2022-08-19 17:07:29,033 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter: Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @alansastre So when you query google with user code in response it sends JSON with `access_token` and `id_token` IF your code request URI has correct grant type. So the id token is an actual JWT, with clams that can be decoded. I managed to decode it with nimbus jose (`SignedJWT.parse()`), grab `subject` claim from it (considering google as trusted source) and generate my own JWT token based on intersection between google subject id and my db data on users.

Comment: @alansastre If you WANT to use google provided token - id_token is the way to go. It seems to work with spring security build in mechanisms for validating JWT if sent with `Authentication: Bearer ...` header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send the id_token to the server (which is a valid JWT) and not the access_token (which is not).